# Responsive design doesn't work properly with Web App

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, responsive-design

I am a music teacher and I built a Web App that allows students to send how many minutes they've practiced each day to a spreadsheet. I used Bootstraps to create a responsive design as you can see in the first picture. When you open the app from Google Apps though, it puts the page in an iframe which is why I'm assuming the responsive design isn't working as it's supposed to. If anyone has any thoughts on how to get around this, please let me know.

Plain HMTL viewed on iPhone:

[image: Plain HMTL viewed on iPhone]

Same HTML running as a published Google App:

[image: Same HTML running as a published Google App]

Edit:
[The responsive design works fine when viewed in Safari "Responsive Design Mode.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Tma7.jpg)

Comment: Bootstrap seems like overkill for a basic form's style.  Do you happen to have the CSS?  I'm not exactly sure what you have at your disposal with Google App Scripts.

Comment: I used Bootstrap because I'm not great at the doing the column aspect of responsive design by hand. Regarding whether I have the CSS, I just applied CSS classes from Bootstrap to various elements on the page. I haven't actually looked at the CSS code.

Comment: It looks like pulling in Bootstrap in its entirety requires a workaround for Google Scripts but I'm not sure if the CSS imports okay and it's just the Javascript/JQuery that's the issue.

Comment: Things work properly in Safari's "Responsive Design Mode." I've edited my post and added a link to a picture of this working perfectly. Also, I'm not using an of the Javascript or JQuery elements of bootstraps. Just the CSS.